# Odd strncpy usage

Tags: c++, string

I've seen a pretty strange (for me) usage of this method:

```
strncpy(somePointer,"%d",someInt);
```

What does this actually do? The integer specifier `"%d"` as the source is troublesome for me to understand.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `sprintf` (or `snprintf`) ?

Comment: It just copies the string `"%d"` to `somePointer`.

Comment: And if it really is `strncpy`, is it the standard `strncpy` function, or a custom one?

Comment: @PaulR yep, double-checked. Standard. I thought it has some more meaningful wizardry kinda usage, not just copying %d

Comment: Just imagine the outrage if it had said `strncpy(somePointer, "int main(){}", someInt)` -- what, reflection in C++?!

Comment: @KerrekSB was a simple question, the specifier part was weird; your example would have been easy to get. Sarcasm much?

Comment: @Ameoo: I may have subconsciously been hoping to make a pedagogical point to increase your confidence in your own code reading skills: If you imagine how you'd react if you had seen any other string in the expression, you might be able to convince yourself that even things that have special meaning elsewhere can be just plain strings. Sometimes a string is just a string.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to use `strncpy()`; despite the name, it's *not* just a safer version of `strcpy()`. See [my blog entry](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html) for more information.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I agree that `strncpy` has an unusual interface. However, it still has a place. For example, if both buffers are dynamically allocated and filled, you might not be able to guarantee correctness with `strcpy` (unless you prepend lots of fix-up code), and `strncpy` may be the most natural choice. If you don't want the fill-it-up semantics, you can use a `min`-expression, I suppose.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Perhaps -- but the majority of calls to `strncpy()` that I've seen are obviously written by programmers who misunderstand it. It would have been nice to have a function that is to `strcpy()` as `strncat()` is to `strcat()` (in fact, setting `target[0] = '\0'` followed by `strncat()` is a good substitute) -- and `strncpy()` *would have* been a good name for such a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does what it says on the tin: It copies the literal string `"%d"` into a char buffer pointed to by `somePointer`, or at least the first `someInt` bytes of it (up to three).

Don't be upset by a percentage sign, it's just another character...

Comment: yep, got it..Except now this code I'm looking into makes no sense :). Will accept it in a few mins.

Comment: @Ameoo: Check if the target string is later used in a `printf`-type situation...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's building a string to pass to one of the printf or scanf (or similar) functions. Code sometimes builds these type of strings on the fly because different circumstances require different types of strings.